# Finding $\alpha$ in $Ax=b$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

I've tried finding $\alpha$ in the following example

$$A=\left[ {\begin{array}{*r}
   2 & { - 1} & 2 & 1  \\
   4 & { - 3} & 0 & 7  \\
   { - 1} & 0 & { - 3} & 2  \\
\end{array}} \right]
,\quad b=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
6 \\
\alpha\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
When using the row reduced echleon form I get the following augmented matrix:
$$A|b=
\left[ {\begin{array}{*r}
   1 & 0 & 3 & { - 2}  \\
   0 & 1 & 4 & { - 5}  \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
\end{array}\left| {\begin{array}{*c}
   0  \\
   0  \\
   1  \\
\end{array}} \right.} \right].
$$

But I would like something like the following, I don't understand why $\alpha$ disapears for me?

[Desired solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Dkh.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is “finding alpha”?

Comment: What is $B$? ${}$

Comment: The short answer could be that you did the calculations incorrectly.

Comment: can you be more specific what you need the $b$ vector ? The rref for matrix A is correct.

Comment: @JesperEgsgaadNielson: My guess is that you had something like $2\alpha-6$ which can be divided to get $\alpha-3$. If you divide that row by the $\alpha-3$, you get the $1$.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: If everything is correct, this means that it's not possible to find an $\alpha$ that solves your system. On the other hand, If it were the case of the last system to have a solution, then any $\alpha$ would work. In the case of the desired solution, $\alpha=3$, is the solution. But, have you divided by $\alpha-3$? This only works in the case where the system does not have any solution, i.e., the case where $\alpha\not=3$, because it's not possible to divide by zero. In the case of an incorrect answer, I would bet that you have divided by zero somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You system can be written as

$\begin{bmatrix} 2 && -1 && 2 && 1 \\ 4 && -3 && 0 && 7 \\ -1 && 0 && -3 && 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 0 \\ 6 && 0 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \alpha \end{bmatrix}$

The augmented matrix of which is

$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc} 2 & -1 & 2 & 1  & 0 & 0  \\ 4 & -3 & 0 & 7  & 6 & 0  \\ -1 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$

Reducing this using the usual Gauss-Jordan elimination, results in

$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc|cc} 1 & 0 & 3 & -2  & 0 & -1  \\ 0 & 1 & 4 & -5  & 0 & -2  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{3} \end{array}\right]$

Thus the system can have solutions only if $ 1 - \dfrac{\alpha}{3} = 0 $, i.e. $\alpha = 3 $.

Comment: Thanks alot for your time!

Comment: @JesperEgsgaardNielsen You're welcome.